# Burning videos to a DVD takes 20 to 25 minutes

Tags: mp4, dvd-burning, rendering

I wish to take 800MB MP4 files and put them onto DVDs so the footage will be playable in a DVD player connected to a TV. All the burning software I have tried takes 20 to 25 minutes to render / burn.

Is there a better, faster way to make a raw mp4 file more usable?  This is used in a jet ski business.

I have tried a bunch of burning programs like Nero and Roxio.  I am using a fast DVD burner drive.  The actual burn time is not the problem. I guess my real question: is there a faster way to encode 800mb MP4 files?

Comment: How are you burning the DVD? Are you authoring a DVD-Video or are you just dragging the files there? Which applications did you try? What is your hardware? Please [edit] your question and add some details.

Comment: Encoding DVDs is a slow process. It takes me up to an hour on a quad core

Comment: Yes, it is not the burning that is the issue, that would only take minutes, even for a full DVD. It is the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The burn time is limited by the physical process of embedding information into the surface of the disk. 20-25 minutes is pretty decent for burning a viewable DVD.

Comment: Not only. If he's burning a DVD-Video, encoding the video to MPEG-2 will probably take much longer than the actual burning itself.

Answer (score 0):

If its for a business, you may want to invest in a DVD copying machine. Here is a search result from this site; [nexttag.com](http://www.nextag.com/dvd-copy-machine/stores-html). I choose a [random one](http://www.produplicator.com/dvd-cd-duplicator-multiple-tower-1-to-1-sony-nec.html) to see if these can be faster. According to that link it can take up to **6 minutes** for a full capacity DVD to encode. However this is some quick googling you may want to investgate further to better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The time to transcode video from MP4 to MPEG2 for DVD will primarily be a function of the processing power of your PC, and to a lesser extent, the speed of your hard drive.  In other words, just get the fastest processor that you can afford.